# Signed driver appears as unsinged in device manager

Tags: certificate, driver, windows-server-2008-r2, sign

Our software using signed drivers, everything works correctly. But for some reasons this driver appear as unsigned in device manager. In our case this makes unwanted warnings in failover cluster validation reports on Windows Server, which may make our customers a bit confused. What may cause such behaviour? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution!
The problem was in missing cross certificate
Signing should look like this:

```
signtool sign /v /f "Cert.pfx" /p pwd /ac "Cross.cer" /t "http://timestamp.server" driver.sys
```

Cross certificates itself can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn170454(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem and found a partial solution.
We were creating the catalog file with makecat from a .cdf file but then I switched to using Inf2Cat and added a CatalogFile entry to the INF file, it worked -- or at least partly. Problem is even though the driver shows up with us as the signer in the Digital Signatures tab, when you click on the Driver Details button inside that tab, the next dialog still shows the driver as unsigned.

Oh well it's progress. Maybe someone will come back with some more info about this.